# Dijkstra's storing the Graph in a text file

Tags: algorithm, matrix, store, dijkstra

I was wondering, what is the most efficient way of storing the graph in a text file while you are implementing Dijkstra's algorithm? (Adjacency matrix, incidence matrix? etc)

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, a good approach is to store a list of all edges.
It takes `O(E)` space: we store two endpoints per edge.
To store it on disk, that will suffice.

To work with such a list, it is usually stored in memory as `V` adjacency lists, one for every vertex.
This duplicates each edge (`u->v` and `v->u`) if the graph is undirected.
However, a common operation for graph algorithms is to traverse all edges from a given vertex.
By storing an adjacency list for each vertex, we get to do that in `O(number of neighbors)`, which is the best possible.

Adjacency matrix takes `O(V^2)` space, which might be fine for dense graphs, but is worse than `O(E)` in the general case.

Incidence matrix takes `O(VE)` space, and is not efficient, unless your graph is somehow very special to make it so.

The fastest implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm take `O(E log V)` time, so `O(E)` memory is usually fine.